# How to solve this Expo Firebase error message

Tags: firebase, initialization, expo

I tried importing {auth, db} from my Firebase file (expo react-native app) and always getting this error message below. What might be the solution?

> Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [following the tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) to get started as this is a basic setup step.

You simply need to call the initializeApp() function as the error states.  Here's a generic example that will work for a web app.

```
<body>
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.6/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <script>
    var firebaseConfig = {
      // This is the firebase config that you get from your Firebase Console under
      // Project Settings -> General -> Your Apps -> App -> Config
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern sir! Have tried this but it still not working

Comment: I would guess that you're invoking firebase somewhere before initializeApp(), but without being able to see your code it's impossible to tell.